# issue with syntax error using google cloud functions

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to understand how to properly execute async operation with google cloud functions. It's seem like I have syntax error but I'm not sure how to fix it. the rest of the code were able to compile work as intended before I added `then()`. please help

***Error:***

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
at new Script (vm.js:51:7)
at createScript (vm.js:138:10)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:199:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:624:28)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

***Area of possible error***

```
if (inviterUID == partnerUID) {
  return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(inviterUID).collection('wallet').doc(uid).set({
  'partnerName': username,
  'browniePoints': 0
}).then(() => {
console.log('testing');
  })
})
```

***Entire Code***

```
exports.checkInviteRequest = functions.firestore
.document('users/{userID}/partnerInviteRequests/{inviterUID}')
.onDelete(invite => {
  const uid = invite.params.userID
  const inviterUID = invite.params.inviterUID
  const deletedInvite = invite.data.previous.data();
  const name = deletedInvite.username;
  return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).get().then(profileInfo => {
      const partnerUID = profileInfo.data().partnerUID
      const username = profileInfo.data().username

      if (inviterUID == partnerUID) {
        return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(inviterUID).collection('wallet').doc(uid).set({
          'partnerName': username,
          'browniePoints': 0
        }).then(() => {
          console.log('testing');
        })
      })
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have closing parenthesis too much on your `if` statement. Specifically the last line of this block:

```
  if (inviterUID == partnerUID) {
    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(inviterUID).collection('wallet').doc(uid).set({
      'partnerName': username,
      'browniePoints': 0
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('testing');
    })
  })
```

That last `)` should not be there. So:

```
  if (inviterUID == partnerUID) {
    return admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(inviterUID).collection('wallet').doc(uid).set({
      'partnerName': username,
      'browniePoints': 0
    }).then(() => {
      console.log('testing');
    })
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your help. is there technique or software that can help me reduce these type of error?

Comment: Well... after the compiler points the problem out, I typically comment out blocks of code to see where the problem is. When the block is small enough, it's a matter of checking each parenthesis to see if it has a counter part.